# Should felt paper overhang an eave drip edge?

Tags: roof

I am replacing my roof shingles and I would like to know if there is a preferred dimension for roofing felt overhang on drip edges.

Comment: Your comment below is confusing. Do you mean _overhang_ or _overlap_? No overhang is recommended for the reasons mentioned below. It would overlap, however.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to overhang the felt underlayment. If you do, it will sag and look sloppy. The important part is to make sure you have the correct overhang of shingles. I usually leave about 1/2-3/4" overhang, even when there is a drip edge.

Here are some [**FEMA Roofing Guidelines**](https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/20130726-1706-25045-9347/chapter8.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Maybe I did not ask my question properly but Texas windstorm requires that the felt underlayment must over hang a portion of the drip edge at the eaves and tucked under the drip edge at the rake.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t like the felt underlayment overhanging the drip edge. It gives the wind a place to “peel” the roof back and wind driven rain entry UNDER the felt.

GAF Roofing Co. does not stipulate an overhang distance, but merely says, “Install a drip edge if required.” ([See Item 1 under Eaves and rakes](https://www.gaf.com/en-us/document-library/documents/productdocuments/residentialroofingdocuments/leakbarriersdocuments/stormguarddocuments/StormGuard__Application_Instructions.pdf))

In your case, it may be required. I’d verify they are referring to the “eave”.